# How to put a different text in jquery ui autocomplete when no search result is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete for my live search bar. What i want is, suppose the user entered some text in the search bar and did not get the desired result, i want to capture the user input whatever he/she has typed.
Below is the js file in which i am doing all the actions related to autocomplete.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
        //$("#inputdefault").easyAutocomplete(options);
        var dynamicProperties = ["contains some of the properties related to my project"];
$( "#inputdefault" ).autocomplete({
      source: dynamicProperties
  });
  });
```

How can this be achieved??
And let me know if some more info is required.

Comment: Where are you getting `dynamicProperties` from ? which event gives you dynamic property

Comment: Here dynamicProperties in my case is an array of string

Answer (score 0):

Firs check if the jquery is loading

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Second dont use this `$(window).load(function() {`

```
$(function() {
        //$("#inputdefault").easyAutocomplete(options);
        var dynamicProperties = ["contains some of the properties related to my project"];
$( "#inputdefault" ).autocomplete({
      source: dynamicProperties
  });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ctz02p5g/

Comment: I am not getting your answer. I think you just copy pasted my code. Can you  please elaborate on the solution.

Comment: dont use this part $(window).load(function() { change for this $(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the code :

```
    (function() { 
//$("#inputdefault").easyAutocomplete(options); 

 var dynamicProperties = ["contains some of the properties related to my project"]; 
$("#inputdefault").autocomplete({
source: function(response) {
    var store = $(this).val(); //stores the value entered so it can be returned back when no result is found.

    if (dynamicProperties.length > 0 ){
            response($.map(dynamicProperties, function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        var1: value[0]                                
                            //return the properties from dynamicProperties
                    };
                }));
            }

            else {
                var results = [{
                    var1: 'result not found',
                    var2: store.slice(-10)

                }];

                response(results);
            }
    }
});
```

Basically we are sending response back while checking if dynamicProperties is getting loaded or not.